# WPF Style Property Trigger not firing on load

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `style trigger` on my Buttons `IsEnabled` property that fires and wiggles my buttons when set to `True`. This works fine if I disable and then re-enable the button from the code behind (MVVM) once the application has loaded and running. However, the `trigger` does not fire on initial load. So all my buttons that are enabled by default do not wiggle. What can I do to make the trigger work on load?

Here is my `Style` from my `App.xaml`

```
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="btnDefaultStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="-5" BeginTime="0:0:0:5.00" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="-5" To="0"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.05" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="4"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.10" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="4"  To="0"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.15" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="-3" BeginTime="0:0:0:5.20" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="-3" To="0"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.25" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="2"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.30" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="2"  To="0"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.35" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource btnDefaultStyle}" />
```

`EventTriggers RoutedEvent`, I.e. `RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded"` is no use as it overrides the Property `IsEnable` event, and therefore my disabled buttons also wiggle.

Comment: Are they meant to wiggle indefinitely, or just for a short moment once the form loads?

Comment: Indefinitely. Every 5 seconds. But only if enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DataTrigger like below :

```
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
             <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                       ...
                 </BeginStoryboard>
             </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
             ...
       </DataTrigger>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
             ...   
       </DataTrigger>
```

This works at load time too.

Comment: If I use EventTriger, I.e. RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded", it wiggles my buttons regardless of the IsEnabled property. So no good.

Comment: Hi @AnjumSKhan, thank you. I have just tried you example and now nothing happens at all. However, it all looks perfect and like it should work. It runs ok without error. Strange. But thank you.

Comment: Hi @AnjumSKhan, I am going to mark your code as the answer as I think it is correct even though for some reason the storyboard does not fire within my application. It sure it is correct as it compiles and runs. I'm guessing it's something else now that is preventing it from working. Thank you again.